# I have rectangles with the numeric results if SQL queries in Superset. How to establish color saturation in HTML code dependind on the output?

Tags: javascript, html, customization, apache-superset

I have 4 rectangles with the numeric results if SQL outputs in Superset. I need somehow to establish color saturation in HTML code depending on the SQL output (without using third-party links or sources).

This is my code which works locally on txt.html file but I want it to be working on Superset.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
        .rectangle {
            width: 100px;
            height: 30px;
            background-color: blue;
            margin: 5px;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            color: white;
        }
    </style>
    <title>Colored Rectangles</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        {% for row in result %}
            {% set value = row[column] %}
            <div class="rectangle" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, {{ value / 10 }});">{{ value }}</div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```